# Get AD Site from LDAP Property

Tags: active-directory

In a domain with AD Sites and Services configured is it possible to get the Site of a computer from LDAP? Is it stored as an attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this has changed over the last couple of years outside of my knowledge, there is not. Historically this was never done as AD site knowledge was ephemeral...the assumption was that computers move around so storing where they are is silly. Plus there was no global need for the knowledge.

You could of course add this. By this i mean, you could do something like, extend the schema with a new attribute for this and set a start-up script on your domain-joined machines to write this (if it has changed since they last wrote) to the directory. Obviously you'll want to test this well to ensure it doesn't create more problems than it solves...

Answer (score 0):

On the Win32 point of view you've got the [DsAddressToSiteNamesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. I don't know how to find it using pure LDAP.